# javascript prototype properties operation

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I want to add a prototype parameter to JavaScript Object witch returns a sum of other parameters.

Why does this work ?:

```
function Item() {
    this.a = 2;
    this.b = 3;
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
}

let it = new Item();
console.log(it.c); //5
```

And this does not ???:

```
function Item() {
    this.a = 2;
    this.b = 3;
}
Item.prototype.c = this.a + this.b;
console.log(it.c); // Nan
```

How to access a property so I can do operations in prototypes properties ?

Or need I to always declare it in the constructor of the Object ?

Comment: `this` outside of the constructor doesn't refer to the instance. Log `this` to console in the constructor and after you've defined the prototype property, you'll see the difference.

Comment: You need a function. The object doesn't even have `a` and `b` values until it is instantiated.